# Combining the result of 3 MySQL tables into one result in PHP sorted by created_at

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Let's say I have 3 DB tables in MySQL:

t1
t2
t3

And each of them has the same columns I am interested in.

And also each of them has some other columns that I am not interested in.

Now, the common columns in all of them I want to put into the final result are `name`, `age`, `created_at`.

And I want to grab all the data (we are not concerned about the performance - it's an intranet application, so, 2 or 3 seconds per query is nothing of concern) and sort them by `created_at` while creating the result.

So, when accessing the result in PHP and doing a while loop the output will be already sorted chronologically.

How to do that in MySQL?

Comment: the join will add tables like t1 > t2 > t3 in sequence. I don't want that. ordering by created_at should be across ALL tables. So, if some date in t3 is earlier than something in t1 or t2 it should be reordered. How to do that?

Comment: I think what you want is something like this `SELECT name, age, created_at FROM t1 UNION SELECT name, age, created_at FROM t2 UNION SELECT name, age, created_at FROM t3 ORDER BY created_at;`.

Comment: This seems to be an example of where you should have a single table, not 3 tables.  It would need an extra column to distinguish the sets of rows, and some composite indexes based on the SELECTs.

Comment: @RickJames Those things of tables are completely unrelated and it is a subject to change based on different things I can't predict. And the number of tables is more than three. I have just simplified it for the sake of easier reasoning ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/union.html) you can put several tables in one query, but the result is handled as one.

Here an example

Table 1

| name | age | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |

Table 2

| name | age | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |

Table 3

| name | age | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 |

```
SELECT name, age, created_at FROM t1
UNION SELECT name, age, created_at FROM t2
UNION SELECT name, age, created_at FROM t3
ORDER BY created_at;
```

| name | age | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 |

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a **UNION** query. This allows you to combine the results of multiple **SELECT** statements into a single result set, which can then be ordered as you require.

```
(SELECT name, age, created_at FROM t1)
UNION
(SELECT name, age, created_at FROM t2)
UNION
(SELECT name, age, created_at FROM t3)
ORDER BY created_at;
```

Note that *UNION* by default removes duplicate rows. If you want to include duplicates, use **UNION ALL** instead.

Ensure that the columns you're combining with *UNION* have compatible data types across all tables.